# Unable to send Micrometer data via statsd to graphite from my Akka actor within Spring Boot 2.0 app

Tags: spring-boot, akka, graphite, statsd, micrometer

I have a Spring Boot 2.0 application and I like to send Micrometer info to a graphite via statsd.

In the application.properties file I added:

```
management.metrics.export.statsd.host=192.168.1.1  // not the real IP
management.metrics.export.statsd.port=8126
management.metrics.export.statsd.step=10s
```

In one of the Akka actors classes I added

```
public class ThePrincessBride extends AbstractActor { 
     private final Counter Inigo = 
            Metrics.counter("my.name.is",  "Inigo", "Montoya");
    ///
    ...
    ///
    private void doX(){
       //do X
       Inigo.increment();
    }
```

The problem is that I don't see this information in Graphite.

I also don't see any relevant network packets leaving my computer when checking the network packets with Wireshark.

- Is it because some missing or wrong configuration?
- Is it because of some conjunction with the Akka actor?
- Do I need some daemon / client on my computer that the program needs to connect to?

Comment: There's lots of things the could be wrong or misconfigured, but it's impossible to tell what based on what you've shared thus far. For example, what dependencies are in your application's pom.xml or build.gradle? A [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve) would make it much easier to see what's going on. Part of producing an MCVE would be to remove Akka and see if the problem still occurs. That would allow you to answer your second question on your own.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the dependency `micrometer-registry-graphite` is simply not on the runtime classpath. Add that dependency and you should be good!